# Play control buttons aren't shown when playing youtube video from uiwebview

Tags: ios, swift, youtube

I'm trying to play a YouTube video inside a UIWebView in Swift, when the video goes on full screen I get a message on the header and the playback buttons aren't shown, I tried everything and tried to use google's YTPlayerView but it is the same issue, please help me solving this issue.

here is the code:

```
let htmlString = "<html><body style='margin:0px;padding:0px;'><script
 type='text/javascript' src='http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'>
</script><script type='text/javascript'>function 
onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){ytplayer=new YT.Player('playerId',{events:
{onReady:onPlayerReady}})}function onPlayerReady(a){}</script><iframe
 id='playerId' type='text/html' width='\(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width)' height='\(self.imageCollectionView.frame.height)' src='\(url!.description)?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&playsinline=1&autoplay=1' frameborder='0'></body></html>"

cell.vedioWebPage.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
cell.vedioWebPage.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false

cell.vedioWebPage.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().resourceURL)
```

and here is a screenshot:

[image]